# NextJS website is not getting new content from Strapi

Tags: reactjs, deployment, static, next.js, strapi

I have my Strapi backend hosted on Heroku.

And my frontend is built using NextJS and hosted on Vercel.

I am using Static generation to build my frontend.

Whenever I write a new blog post on Strapi, I have to go to Vercel and rebuild the frontend.

Is there a way that my frontend automatically reflects the new blog post and I don’t have to rebuild the website every time?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Best approach for an app with +150k static pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66037031/1870780)? You can use `fallback: true` or `fallback: blocking` in `getStaticPaths` so that the new blog posts get generated.

Comment: @juliomalves, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.